# Não recebo email via PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer, xampp, gmail

Estou utilizando o PHPMailer para envio de mensagem via formulário, porém não está funcionando. Gostaria de saber onde estou errando. Lembrando que o email que irá receber as informações do formulário é Gmail. Segue meu código para melhor entendimento.

HTML:

```
<form id="main-contact-form" name="contact-form" action="mail.php" method="post">
    <div class="row  wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome" required="required">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" required="required">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Assunto" required="required">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Escreva sua Mensagem" required="required"></textarea>
    </div>                        
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn-submit">Enviar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
    <?php
$Nome       = $_POST["name"];   // Pega o valor do campo Nome
$Email       = $_POST["email"];   // Pega o valor do campo Telefone
$Assunto      = $_POST["subject"];  // Pega o valor do campo Email
$Mensagem   = $_POST["message"];   // Pega os valores do campo Mensagem

// Variável que junta os valores acima e monta o corpo do email

$Vai        = "Nome: $Nome\n\nE-mail: $Email\n\nAssunto: $Assunto\n\nMensagem: $Mensagem\n";
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
require_once("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");

define('GUSER', 'tecmovlocacao@gmail.com');   // <-- Insira aqui o seu GMail
define('GPWD', 'senhaaaa');        // <-- Insira aqui a senha do seu GMail

function smtpmailer($para, $de, $de_nome, $assunto, $corpo) { 
    global $error;
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->isSMTP();       // Ativar SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;       // Debugar: 1 = erros e mensagens, 2 = mensagens apenas
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // Autenticação ativada
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'SSL';  // SSL REQUERIDO pelo GMail
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';// SMTP utilizado
    $mail->Port = 465;          // A porta 587 deverá estar aberta em seu servidor
    $mail->Username = GUSER;
    $mail->Password = GPWD;
    $mail->SetFrom($de, $de_nome);
    $mail->Subject = $assunto;
    $mail->Body = $corpo;
    $mail->AddAddress($para);
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
        return false;
    } else {
        $error = 'Mensagem enviada!';
        return true;
    }
}

// Insira abaixo o email que irá receber a mensagem, o email que irá enviar (o mesmo da variável GUSER), 

 if (smtpmailer('tecmovlocacao@gmail.com', 'tecmovlocacao@gmail.com', 'renata', 'Assunto do Email', $Vai)) {

    Header("location:http://www.dominio.com.br/obrigado.html"); // Redireciona para uma página de obrigado.

}
if (!empty($error)) echo $error;
?>
```

Hierarquia de pastas:

```
TECMOV
- css/
- fonts/
- images/
- js/
- phpmailer/
- index.php
- mail.php
```

Comment: Kirito, cuidado ao postar código com usuário e senha originais, sempre tente renomear para algo que não comprometa a segurança de suas informações, vamos acreditar que ninguém viu e que ninguém ira acessar o histórico de edição para ver. mude sua senha

Comment: obrigado eu me esqueci de modificala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos lá:

- A porta do [SMTP do Gmail](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=pt) não é 25, e sim 465 (SSL) ou 587 (TLS);
- Caso esse email tenha autenticação em duas etapas, você deve desativá-la;
- Você tem um limite de 2000 mensagens por dia;
- Na documentação do PHPMailer, há um exemplo de [envio via Gmail](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps);
- `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;` não significa o que está no seu comentário, e sim o que está na [documentação](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.html#property_SMTPDebug):

> ### `$SMTPDebug:`
>
> *SMTP class debug output mode.*
>
> **Debug output level. Options:**
>
> - 0 No output
> - 1 Commands
> - 2 Data and commands
> - 3 As 2 plus connection status
> - 4 Low-level data output

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Ola amigo obrigado pelo post so nao entendi o segundo passo

Comment: amigo fiz o pssao a apasso e editei meu documento porem agora aparece esse erro:  Fatal error: Class 'SMTP' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\TECMOV\phpmailer\class.phpmailer.php on line 1439

Comment: O segundo passo é referente a autenticação em duas etapas (você digita a senha do email e depois digita um código, que foi enviado via SMS, aplicativo, ou outro modo). Se o email usado para enviar tiver essa autenticação ativada, você deverá desativá-la. Sobre o erro que você falou, você alterou algo que não devia... Poste o código atualizado, talvez?

Comment: irei fazer isso agora de uma lhada nesse código atualizado que irei postar em instantes

Comment: pronto esta ai o codigo editado dei uma olhada tambm no link que voce me mandou e tbm alterei meu php.ini fui na linha smtp_port ela estava em 25 e coloquei ela e 465 mais memo assim aparece esse erro--- 
Fatal error: Class 'SMTP' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\TECMOV\phpmailer\class.phpmailer.php on line 1439

Comment: Você deve fazer o require do `PHPMailerAutoload.php` para resolver esse erro, também deve desabilitar a autenticação em duas etapas que **está** ativa nesse seu email para conseguir usar o script. Considere seguir o [exemplo do próprio PHPMailer](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps)

Comment: autenticaçao de duas etapas no meu gmail ela fica em configuralçoes e isso ?

Comment: amigo funcionou fiz um teste e deu certo porem quando enviei 2 segundo formulario ja nao funcionou deu o seguinte erro:Mail error: SMTP Connect() falhou. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: consegui arrumar obrigado pela sua ajuda marqui sua resposta como aceita ^^^

Comment: @Kirito bom saber que deu certo!